# Best way to negate values in a datatable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, dataset

I have a data table filled with data . I need to negate the values in one column. ie, If the column has a positive value, it has to be converted to negative and vice versa. What is the best possible way to perform this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something along the lines of:

```
foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
  row["column_name"] *= -1;
}
```

Where `table` is your `DataTable`.

Comment: I don't think DataTable is enumerable. I think it should be foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows) {...}

Comment: @ xcaliburp Yes ..    @ dandan..Thanks for the answer. But is there  a better approcah as my data-table may contain 5 million records ?

Comment: @ Ananth: Would there be any other way if you wanted to perform the same operation on, say, an array? You have to perform an operation on each element and there's no getting around it. There might be a syntactically different technique, but I would expect the outcome to be the same.